how to retain plus symbol in email address in b2c policy
Sign up link will append email with + symbol
&login_hint=test+aaa@test.com

In policy, I get the {OIDC:LoginHint}
<InputClaims>
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" />
</InputClaims>

But signInName doesn't retain + symbol. I get email as test aaa@test.com
how to retain + symbol in email address

I found the solution for my question. I need to send encoded email. Then {OIDC:LoginHint} return correct email.
&login_hint=test%2Baaa%40test.com

